# How to find and replace multiple field values using jq?

Tags: sed, json, jq

In the following json file,

```
{
  "email": "xxx",
  "pass": "yyy",
  "contact": [
    {
      "id": 111,
      "name": "AAA"
    }
  ],
  "lname": "YYY",
  "name": "AAA",
   "group": [
    {
      "name": "AAA",
      "lname": "YYY",
    }
  ],
```

I need to look for the key "name" and replace its value to "XXX" at all places. Which jq command does that ?

Answer (score 24):

jq's assignment operations can perform an update on as many locations at once as you can name and are made for this sort of situation. You can use

```
jq '(.. | .name?) |= "XXXX"'
```

to **find every field called "name" anywhere and replace the value in each all at once** with "XXXX", and output the resulting object.

This is just the `..|.a?` example from the [recursive-descent documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..) combined with [update assignment](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=).

It uses the [recursive descent operator `..`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..) to find every single value in the tree, then pulls out the "name" field from each of them [with `.name`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectIdentifier-Index:.foo,.foo.bar), [suppresses any errors from non-matching values with `?`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ErrorSuppresion/OptionalOperator:?), and then updates the object in all those places at once with "XXXX" using the [update-assignment operator `|=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=), and outputs the new object.

This will work no matter what the file structure is and update every name field everywhere.

---

Alternatively, if the file always has this structure, and it's **those particular "name" fields you want to change**, not just any old name, you can also just list them out and assign to them as a group as well:

```
jq '(.name, .contact[].name, .group[].name) |= "XXXX"'
```

This does the same assignment to

1. the "name" field of the top-level object;
2. the "name" field of *every* object in the "contact" array; and
3. the "name" field of every object in the "group" array.

all in one go. This is particularly useful if the file might have *other* name fields in there somewhere unrelated that you don't want to change. It finds just the three sets of locations named there and updates them all simultaneously.

---

If the value is just a literal like it is here then [plain assignment with `=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Plainassignment:=) works too and saves you a character: `(..|.name?)="XXXX"` - you'd also want this if your value is computed based on the whole top-level object. If instead you want to compute the new name based on the old one, you *need* to use `|=`. If I'm not sure what to use, `|=` generally has slightly nicer behaviour in the corner cases.

If you have **multiple replacements to do**, you can pipe them together:

```
jq '(..|.name?) = "XXXX" | (..|.lname?) = "1234"'
```

will update both the "name" and "lname" fields everywhere, and output the whole updated object once.

---

A few other approaches that may work:

- You could also be really explicit about what you're selecting with

  ```
    (..|objects|select(has("name"))).name |= "XXXX"`
  ```

which finds everything, then just the objects, then just the objects that have a "name", then the name field on those objects, and performs the same update as before.

- If you're running the development version of jq (unlikely) then the [`walk` function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#walk(f)) can also do the job: `walk(.name?="XXXX")`. All the other versions will work on the latest released version, 1.5.
- An alternative multi-update could be

  ```
    jq '(..|select(has("name"))?) += {name: "XXXX", lname: "1234"}'
  ```

which finds everything *with* a name and then sets both "name" and "lname" on each object using [arithmetic update-assignment `*=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Arithmeticupdate-assignment:+=,-=,*=,/=,%25=,//=) and the [merging behaviour that `+` has for objects](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Addition:+).

Comment: `jq '(.. | .name?) |= "XXXX"'` has the undersired effect to introduce the value "name" where it was previously null, I want to replace only the values that exist.

Comment: @MauroGiusti You may prefer one of the other options further down the answer, then, particularly the ones using `select` if "key exists" is the main factor.

Answer (score 8):

Using `jq` based on the `walk` function (needs a recent version):

```
jq 'walk(.name?="XXX")' file
```

If your `jq` doesn't support the `walk` function, just define it as:

```
jq '
  # Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
  def walk(f):
    . as $in
    | if type == "object" then
       reduce keys[] as $key
         ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
    elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
    else f
    end;
  walk(.name?="XXX")
' file
```

Credits: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/963

Comment: Hi I get the following error.
error: Invalid character
walk(.name?="XXX")
          ^

Comment: @user2181698 are you sure you're running that command on linux/unix?

Comment: Perhaps @user2181698 is using an unusual shell and neglected to mention it?

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, *[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)* based solution:

```
bash $ jtc -w'<name>l+0' -u'"XXX"' your.json 
{
   "contact": [
      {
         "id": 111,
         "name": "XXX"
      }
   ],
   "email": "xxx",
   "group": [
      {
         "lname": "YYY",
         "name": "XXX"
      }
   ],
   "lname": "YYY",
   "name": "XXX",
   "pass": "yyy"
}
bash $
```